# Find all code / scripts related to a specific page

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

(iam editing a existing website)
Iam trying to add a background slider to my homepage, this same slider is already applied to a page in the website, and is working good. When I try to add it to my front page using this code:

```
 if (is_front_page()) {

    echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider="2"]');
}
```

It glitches the front page, probably because I need to add same css that is already applied to the page the working slider is in.

code used to display it on the working page:

```
if (is_page('maalderij')) {

    echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider="2"]');
}
```

Now, iam hoping there is some kind of way to find all scripts, code and css etc. related to a specific page. I think the page that works has a script or something that blocks this code from working on that page:

```
<?php elseif($backgroundImage) : ?>
    <figure class="content-featured-image mb-0 proj2">
        <?php echo $backgroundImage; ?>
        <div class="scroll-to-content d-flex d-lg-none"><i class="fal fa-angle-down fa-2x"></i></div>
    </figure>
    <div class="scroll-to-content d-flex d-lg-none"><i class="fal fa-angle-down fa-2x"></i></div>

<?php endif;
```

and probably also add some other classes or styles to display the slider correctly. BUT I can't find what does this.

edit: I've already tried searching the page url name and id with string locater plugin.

Comment: You could look/find code references to your smartslider: `grep -lr 'smartslider3' .`.  And also check the smartslider code?

Comment: Your question is currently off-topic for SO, if you could reword it as to what your problem is, what you've tried, and how it currently fails.  You may get more traction.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask